# JPA Criteria query eager fetch associated entities using a SINGLE query with joins instead of multiple queries

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-criteria

We are moving from Hibernate native criteria to JPA criteria queries in scope of upgrading a hibernate from 4.3.11 to 5.2.12 and found out different behavior. Previously hibernate criteria use a single query with joins to eager fetch one-to-many associated entities, but JPA use separate queries to fetch the associated entities for each root entity.

I know I can explicitly set fetch mode like `entityRoot.fetch("attributes", JoinType.INNER);` but we need to do it in some AbstractDao implementation that should work for any eager one-to-many association so can't explicitly set this.

So can I somehow tell JPA criteria to eager fetch associated entities in a single query using joins by default instead of separate queries for each root entity?

The code example:

```
    CriteriaBuilder builder = createCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(getEntityClass());
    Root<T> entityRoot = criteriaQuery.from(getEntityClass());

    criteriaQuery.select(entityRoot);
    criteriaQuery.where(builder.equal(entityRoot.get("param1"), "value"));

    return getEntityManager().createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
```

Comment: `JPA use separate queries` - JPA is just a specification, it's still hibernate that does the actual queries

Comment: Correct, JPA implementation by hibernate now uses separate queries.

Answer (score 3):

#### Short answer

You can't configure it in such a way, but you may implement the necessary behavior.

#### Long answer

As you may read in [Hibernate 5.2 User Guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching), there are several ways to apply a fetching strategy:

- @Fetch [annotation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-fetch-annotation)
- JPQL/HQL query - [fetch join](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-explicit-join)
- JPA Criteria query - [FetchParent::fetch](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/FetchParent.html#fetch(java.lang.String,%20javax.persistence.criteria.JoinType))
- JPA entity graph - [attributeNodes](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-strategies-dynamic-fetching-entity-graph)
- Hibernate profile - [fetchOverrides](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-strategies-dynamic-fetching-profile)

`@Fetch` annotation is a *static* way to apply fetching strategy, and the `FetchMode.JOIN` works exactly as you've described:

> Inherently an EAGER style of fetching. The data to be fetched is
>   obtained through the use of an SQL outer join.

The problem is, even if you would mark your `attributes` collection with the `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)` annotation, it would be [overridden](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-fetchmode-join):

> The reason why we are not using a JPQL query to fetch multiple
>   Department entities is because the FetchMode.JOIN strategy would be
>   overridden by the query fetching directive.
>
> To fetch multiple relationships with a JPQL query, the JOIN FETCH
>   directive must be used instead.
>
> Therefore, FetchMode.JOIN is useful for when entities are fetched
>   directly, via their identifier or natural-id.

JPA Criteria query without `FetchParent::fetch` would do the same.

Since you need a universal solution for an abstract DAO, the possible way is to process all eager one-to-many associations with reflection:

```
    Arrays.stream(getEntityClass().getDeclaredFields())
            .filter(field ->
                    field.isAnnotationPresent(OneToMany.class))
            .filter(field ->
                    FetchType.EAGER == field.getAnnotation(OneToMany.class).fetch())
            .forEach(field ->
                    entityRoot.fetch(field.getName(), JoinType.INNER));
```

Of course, calling reflection for every query would be inefficient. You may obtain all loaded `@Entity` classes from [Metamodel](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/metamodel/Metamodel.html), process them, and store results for further use:

```
    Metamodel metamodel = getEntityManager().getMetamodel();
    List<Class> entityClasses = metamodel.getEntities().stream()
            .map(Type::getJavaType)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    Map<Class, List<String>> fetchingAssociations = entityClasses.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Function.identity(),
                    aClass -> Arrays.stream(aClass.getDeclaredFields())
                            .filter(field -> 
                                    field.isAnnotationPresent(OneToMany.class))
                            .filter(field -> 
                                    FetchType.EAGER == field.getAnnotation(OneToMany.class).fetch())
                            .map(Field::getName)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            ));
```